# C# Reverse the first 2 digits of an unknown digit number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm making a game, where you have to calculate the next number in the fibonnaci seq. on a timer

```
Ex.  0, 1 => next number = 1
     1, 2 => next number = 3
     2, 3 => next number = 5
```

And so on...

The thing is... once you get to bigger numbers, that are harder to calculate, you would want to do basic addition, from right to left. So you have 2 options, either do it in your mind, or type it down and reverse the number after, which is exactly what I have coded it to do.

It is reversing the number, using the normal algorithm for it, but there is one problem.

Normally, you go from right to left with the math, and type every digit down, and once you get to adding the last digits of the 2 numbers, if the sum of these 2 goes over 10, you just write the number before the other digits

```
Ex:
```

567 + 723

```
1. 7 + 3 => 0                      Number = 0
2. 6 + 2 = 8 + the carried 1 = 9   Number = 90
3. 5 + 7 = 12                      Number = 1290
```

In the input bar, you would type it like **0912**, but that wouldn't work since the **12** has to be reversed as well into **21**. Since I don't want this to be a nuisance for the player, the question is

**How do I reverse the first digits 2 digits of a number?**

My guess would be adding 1 variable that stores the reversed sum of the numbers, and then 2 other variables storing the number after the first 2 digits in one, and the other one storing the first 2 digits and reversing them, then adding the first 2 digits reversed to the other part multiplied by 100

Even so, I don't believe it is my best options, since I can't be sure if the numbers are 3 digits with sum >999 or normal 4 digits with the sum <9999

If you have any better ideas, please tell me.
If you have any questions about my code, I'll gladly post it
My apologies if this is hard to understand, the human mind is hard to explain.

Comment: Why not just add the numbers?

Comment: Why are you asking a user to add two numbers, make a presumption that their mind will add the numbers like your mind does, allow them to use your program as a scratchpad based on your presumption, and then fix up the final part of the sum for them based on how you've presumed it's done? It all falls apart if the presumption is wrong, such as if they do 500+700=1200,60+20=80,7+3=10,1200+60+10=1290 or "borrow 3 from 723 to make 720 and 570, then borrow 20 for 590, then 7+5 is 1290"

Comment: If you were doing anything like what your question title was you would have a very different answer

Comment: @Caius Jard , If i got this right, then my answer would be the fact that this is not meant to be used as a scratchpad. You have time on every submission and you have to do it as fast as possible. The human mind can do simple operations in an instant, but once it comes down to borrowing, we tend to lose ourselves. Currently the time you have on every answer is depending on how many sums of each digit of each number go over 9, cause then you have to carry, and it's a little harder. So in fact, the normal addition algorithm is meant to be the best imo.

Comment: You're doing it again -> "the normal addition method" presumes that all humans add numbers like you do. A huge section of the population adds via a method called chunking, which is nothing like what do you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple way is this (see it live [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iH5XU6)):

```
public static long SwapFirstTwoDigits(long val)
{
    if(val < 10) return val;
    
    long mask;
    for(mask = 1; mask < val; mask *= 10) {}
    mask /= 100; // two back
    
    var firstTwoDigits = val / mask;
    return val % mask + (firstTwoDigits % 10) * mask * 10 + firstTwoDigits / 10 * mask;
}
```

Basically you build the base 10 mask of all the digits you want to leave alone (so two behind the first two digits from the right) and simply swap the rest with modulo arithmetic.

Output from the linked fiddle:

```
Input: 1530, Output: 5130
Input: 16789, Output: 61789
Input: 34, Output: 43
Input: 3, Output: 3
Input: 0, Output: 0
```

Comment: This did the job perfectly, with beautiful code. Thank you!

Comment: In this particular application, given that performance is unimportant, I think I would have taken the easier-to-understand method of converting the number to a string, swapping the lead characters, and converting it back